# How to bind Custom Object to ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, custom-object

I am new to WPF so please accept my apologies if my question is stupid.

I am creating a food ordering system which consists of 2 main sections, the "Food Menu" and the "Order List". When user chooses an item from the food menu, it will be added to the a listbox control which represents the order list.

I have created a few custom objects: `Order`, `OrderLine`, `Item`, as well as a Collection class, `OrderLineCollection`, for "OrderLine". They look like the following:

```
public class Order
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public double TotalAmt { get; set; }
    public OrderLineCollection LineItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double SubTotal { get { return unitPrice * quantity; } }
}

[Serializable]
public class OrderLineCollection : CollectionBase
{
    public OrderLine this[int index]
    {
        get { return (OrderLine)List[index]; }
        set { List[index] = value; }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

My `ListBox` control has a `DataTemplate` so that more details are shown for each item. The XAML as below:

```
<Page x:Class="FoodOrdering.OrderList"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      Title="Order List">
    <ListBox Name="lbxOrder" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">            
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="{Binding item.name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="x "/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding quantity}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding subTotal, Converter={StaticResource priceConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,5,0,0" Click="btnDelete_Click">Delete</Button>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Page>
```

so when items are added, the ListBox will look like the below image:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6322828/orderList.png

In the code-behind, I have created a static variable `currentOrder` for storing the current order and it will be used by other classes/methods.

And every time its value is changed, the following stupid method `LoadCurrentOrder()` is called to refresh the ListBox view.

```cs
public partial class OrderList : Page
{
    public static Order currentOrder = new Order();
    public OrderList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadCurrentOrder();
    }

    public void LoadCurrentOrder()
    {
        lbxOrder.Items.Clear();
        foreach (OrderLine ol in currentOrder.LineItems)
            lbxOrder.Items.Add(ol);
    }
}
```

My problem is how can I bind the data in an elegant way (such as using `Resources` `ItemsSource` and so on) instead of using the above method, so that the ListBox will update automatically every time the value of the variable is changed?

I tried

```
lbxOrder.ItemsSource = currentOrder;
```

but it does not work as currentOrder is not a `System.Collections.IEnumerable` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - Don't create your own collection types, the .Net framework Base Class Library already has pretty much everything you need.

Remove the `OrderLineCollection` and use an `ObservableCollection<OrderLine>`.

2 - Try to stick to MVVM conventions. This means you should not manipulate UI elements in code.

```
public OrderList()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadCurrentOrder();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

then in XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LineItems}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

3 - Do not name UI elements in XAML unless you need to reference them in XAML. This will help  you reconsider your approach every time you find yourself wanting to manipulate UI elements in procedural code.

4 - Get used to the C# naming convention. Property names should be "proper cased" (I.E `LineItems` instead of `lineItems`)

Comment: Thanks for convention tips especially the naming one, guess I have messed up the concept for long time... I have edited the property names in case others may get confused
`ObservableCollection` works fine in my WPF project. But what if I create the classes in a Class Library project? I tried and it looks like `ObservableCollection` only supports in XAML usage?

Comment: @pblyt the [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.100).aspx) class is defined in the `System.dll` assembly, therefore it is a core part of the .Net BCL, it is in no way dependant on any WPF assemblies or classes.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to make the `lineItems` property into an `ObservableCollection<yourType>`. Then when this collection is changed (items added, removed) the listbox will refresh automatically.

If your problem is that the order itself changes and you need to refresh the listbox. Then all you need to do is to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and when the order changes, to trigger the notification that the property has changed and the UI will refresh via the binding.

As for the binding in a more elegant way. You can bind to the `currentOrder.lineItems`:

```
lbxOrder.ItemsSource = currentOrder.lineItems;//this should be an observable collection if you intend to have items change
```

Comment: Thanks @dutzu, `ObservableCollection` works fine in my WPF project. But what if I create the classes in a Class Library project and I add it as reference in WPF project? I tried and it looks like `ObservableCollection` only supports in XAML usage.

Comment: You can always wrap a List of objects that you receive from the Class Library as an ObservableCollection to serve your UI needs.